# 'chromedriver_mac64' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Tags: python, google-chrome

I cannot get this to work and have never had this issue before

I have tried to manually put the file in the folder and run with sudo no success

'chromedriver_mac64' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.46-py3.7.egg/instapy_chromedriver/chromedriver_mac64'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Inna/Desktop/InstaPy-master/instapy/browser.py", line 146, in set_selenium_local_session
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_mac64' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 13, in 
    session = InstaPy()
  File "/Users/Inna/Desktop/InstaPy-master/instapy/instapy.py", line 295, in **init**
    self.set_selenium_local_session()
  File "/Users/Inna/Desktop/InstaPy-master/instapy/instapy.py", line 349, in set_selenium_local_session
    raise InstaPyError(err_msg)
instapy.exceptions.InstaPyError: ensure chromedriver is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/instapy_chromedriver-2.46-py3.7.egg/instapy_chromedriver/chromedriver_mac64
Innas-MacBook-Pro:instapy-master Inna$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29})

It should open chrome and begin the script at this point however I keep getting errors